# Trying to Call a LabVIEW dll into python that invokes a CAN protocol

Tags: python, dll, labview

I was wondering if anybody could help me make sense of this error. I am calling a LabVIEW generated dll in python that communicates to a DCM via a CAN protocol.

The structure and input parameters of the LabVIEW function called in Python is as follows:

```
int32_t func_1(CStr version_number, int32_t Verbose, CStr SetupFileName);
```

I know that the dll is imported into Python, and that the parameters are being input correctly because other functions with the same structure have the same input parameters and they don't return an error.

```
import ctypes as c

mydll = c.windll.LoadLibrary('intcan.dll') #'C:/Users/PycharmProjects/impdll/intcan.dll')

mydll.func_1(c.c_char_p('15.1.1.1'), c.c_int(0), c.c_char_p('CanDevice.xml'))
```

When I run the code I get the following error.

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Users/PycharmProjects/impdll/venv/tester.py", line 22, in <module>
    mydll.func_1(c.c_wchar_p('15.1.1.1'), c.c_int(0), c.c_wchar_p('CanDevice.xml'))
OSError: [WinError -529697949] Windows Error 0xe06d7363

Process finished with exit code 1
```

Comment: Do you perchance use a 64bit version of python (well, ctypes most importantly) and a 32bit version of a windows dll? If so, that might be your problem.

Comment: I checked to see if the bit versions were consistent and both Python and the dll were 32 bit.

Comment: Did you build the DLL? Have you successfully communicated with the device at all, either on the same machine or a different one, and either using the DLL or by some other method?

Comment: I did not build the DLL. It has successfully communicated with the device through calling it in LabVIEW directly using a different computer. But for some reason in python it won't work even on the computer that called it successfully in LabVIEW. Some of the dll functions are callable in Python and execute correctly, but others give the OSError: [WinError -529697949] Windows Error 0xe06d7363

Comment: Possible stupid suggestion here: have you tried running that script as administrator? Other possible stupid suggestion: If it works in LabView, why not just use python to call the LabView script that calls the DLL?

Comment: My first thought was whether you have the correct LabVIEW runtime engine installed, but if some DLL functions work I guess it's not that (maybe still worth checking though? also any driver for the CAN interface?). From a web search on the hex error code `0xe06d7363` I find [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19500846/what-is-a-microsoft-c-exception) which seems relevant but unhelpful, if you see what I mean. If you can liaise with the LabVIEW author I would probably take this to National Instruments support, and/or their forums if you don't have an SSP subscription.

Comment: Meanwhile if you need a workaround the best I can suggest is ask the LabVIEW author to create an exe instead which you can call with command line parameters or a TCP/IP interface or something.

Comment: OK, you've confirmed that Python can call functions in your DLL. I'm guessing your DLL is failing to (dynamically) load another DLL that's required for CAN communication (NI-CAN or NI-XNET). The other calls succeed because those functions don't need the CAN DLL. Do you know what drivers are needed by that DLL? See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13360718/python-ctypes-and-dll-that-uses-a-com-object for a similar problem.

Answer (score 0):

There are a number of ways in which you can configure a string to be passed into a function in a LabVIEW DLL.

If the string is just an input, the easiest way is to set:

- Param Type: Input
- Pass By: C String Pointer

which would yield this function prototype:

```
void func_1(char MyString[])
```

you can then call in Python as:

```
import ctypes as c

mydll = c.windll.LoadLibrary('mydll.dll')
mydll.func_1("myValue".encode("ascii"))
```